# Concatenate/Merge values based on multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can you concatenate/join or merge values based on multiple columns?

This is the initial table

| Name | Height | Weight | Class number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | 1m80 | 80kg | 1 |
| Steve | 1m60 | 60kg | 2 |
| Bob | 1m60 | 60kg | 2 |

Based on the height, the weight and the class, if they match all then write in a new column the following output:

| Names of people that share a lot in common (height,weight and class number) |
| --- |
| Steve,Bob |

Comment: Index() with match() using countifs() possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on ***Microsoft-365*** then could try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($A$2:$A$4,($B$2:$B$4=B2)*($C$2:$C$4=C2)*($D$2:$D$4=D2)))
```

[image]